# Append for-loop output to a single array

Tags: python, list, for-loop, output

Given that `print((sum(int(record[-1]) for record in groupOfRecords)))` outputs:

```
0
0
0
2
10
0
0
0
0
2
10
0
0
0
0
6
0
0
```

After appending each int output to an empty array `groups`:

`groups.append((sum(int(record[-1]) for record in groupOfRecords)))`

`print(groups)` outputs the following:

```
[0]
[0, 0]
[0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 2]
[0, 0, 0, 2, 10]
[0, 0, 0, 2, 10, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 2, 10, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 2, 10, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 2, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 2, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2]
[0, 0, 0, 2, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 10]
[0, 0, 0, 2, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 10, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 2, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 10, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 2, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 10, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 2, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 2, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6]
[0, 0, 0, 2, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 2, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0]
```

Whereas the desired result is simply the last array: `[0, 0, 0, 2, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0]` in order for `print(sum(groups))` to output `30`

Comment: You probably have `print(groups)` in your for loop. remove it and only print it when the for loop is done. That being said, `print(sum(groups))` should work regardless, since it takes the last value of `groups` (which is `[0, 0, 0, 2, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0]`).

Comment: So what is your question? Are you asking how to take the last element from a list? You already know that.

Comment: I also doubt that the first expression prints that. It should only print a single value with no line breaks (that single value being a `<generator object ...>`).

Comment: @Damiaan Ah, yes that was it. I need to get some coffee. Thank you!